# Updating rails model's tags with null id issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails modle like this

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags

  def all_tags=(keys)
    self.tags = keys.split(',').map do |key|
      Tag.where(article_id: id, key: key.strip).first_or_create!
    end
  end

  def all_tags
    tags.map(&:key).join(', ')
  end
end
```

Basically what I want to do is to allow user set tags on it, it would look like this in controller

```
  def create
    @article = article(article_params)
    if @ article.persisted?
      redirect_to article s_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

However, as in `def all_tags=(keys)`, `article.id` is not present yet. So I got error like this

```
PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "article_id" violates not-null constraint
```

Here is the question, how to ensure article is persisted before `all_tags` got update?

Comment: what if you change `first_or_create` with `first_or_initialize`?

Comment: where is all_tags method being called?

Comment: @Nithin it's from `article_params`, like {article: {all_tags: 'foo,bar,spam,eggs'}  }

Comment: well then you might want to first check if article is persisted, so changing the all_tags method name and calling it after the check seems a better option.

Comment: @Aguardientico hey, your solution solved my problem, can you post a simple answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @VictorLin Done, then answer is below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `Model.where(conditions).first_or_create!`, Active Record tries to insert into database a new record for `Model` if can't found one.

In your case, since you are setting the attributes before save the model, then the `create` launch an exception.

To fix the issue just change `first_or_create` with `first_or_initialize`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do validation something like
validates :your_method, on: :update

def your_method
{with logic not be null}
end